# Global array works in function with alert/console.log, but not when indexed with variable

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue referencing a global array within a function.  Below is the basics of what's going on.  Why can't I reference the array this way? How can I access this array from within the second function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myData = [];

$(function() {
   myData.push([1,2,3]);
});

console.log(myData); // Works

$(".btn").click(function() {
   var i = 0;

   console.log(myData[i]); // Works
   alert(myData[i]);  // Works

   for (i; i<myData[0].length; i++) {
      if (myData[0][i] == 2) {
        break;
      }
   }

   newNum = myData[0][i];  // myData[i] is undefined.
                           // Doesn't like window.myData[i] either.
});

</script>
```

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me. Would you mind placing it in a JsFiddle or JsBin?

Comment: I don't think that code does what you describe, not least because you're not initializing the array until the `ready` event fires (as you've used the shorthand version of `$(document).ready(...)`, but you're using the contents of it before that happens. As the script shown doesn't have `defer` or `async`, the ready event won't have already fired (unless this is being loaded via ajax).

Comment: Side note: There is no purpose whatsoever to the `i` at the beginning of `for (i; i<myData[0].length; i++) {`. I would recommend putting `i = 0` there instead, rather than initializing it up at the top of the function, well away from the loop.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That sounds right. How should I structure it so the data is initialized before I try to assign the value to newNum?

Comment: @vincent: Your comments in the code don't fit with the premise of my comment. But what you would do is move all of your code into the callback you're passing into `$(...)`, rather than only having the code initializing `myData` there. This also has the advantage that `myData` can stop being genuinely global, and only be global to your code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: So initialize myData within the click function? That would probably work, but the array is actually pretty huge, so I'm trying to only do it on the page load.  Sorry, I'm a novice.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Also, I didn't know about the defer / async thing. I thought the $(document).ready(...), just runs the function as soon as the page is downloaded, then if I waited long enough to click the btn, the data would be initialized.

Comment: @vincent: I don't know what the array's for, so I can't comment on whether it makes sense to initialize it in the `click` handler. This is all I meant about the `ready` callback: http://pastie.org/8908148